# Find maximum number of Candies

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of numbers. We can select 3 numbers at a time from the array.

Suppose A, B, C where A <= B <= C. You get B number candy from this selection.

You can pick one element only once. You need to maximize number of candies.

Note: The size of array will be multiple of 3.

Ex:
[4,5,6,7,8,9]

output:

14

Explanation:

We selected [4,8,9] first, then [5,6,7] so the max no. of candies: 8+6=14

Comment: Yes, we understand what you mean. What is the question?

Comment: Greedy algorithm。Cause u know , the last 2 position must be [8,9] & [6,7] .

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Question is to find maximum number of candies we can get.

Comment: @cowboi-peng could you explain a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.first，we know **A <= B <= C** ，so we know we should chose a max B, but must < C, so we can only chose less max , in this case is **(nums.length - 1) - 1**. A we will chose the first one,but it doesn't matter
2.we chose the second array , B will be nums.length - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
3.So we found the result : result += nums[nums.length -1 -i*2 -1]

```java
    public static int maxCandies(int[] nums){
        Arrays.sort(nums); // sort the array
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<nums.length/3;i++)
            result += nums[nums.length-1-i*2-1]; // always add the less max num
        return result;
    }
```